# R Studio upgrade

Tags: r, rstudio

I am kinda confused with upgrading R Studio. I have two questions.

1) As of today, July 10th 2017, is (RStudio v1.0.147 Preview) the most recent version? I've included the link to this version: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

2) I already have R studio on my cpu ( I don't know which version). 
I would like to download the most recent version of R studio.

So, if I do need to download the abovementioned version, do I uninstall my current R Studio and then install it again from the above link? Or do I NOT need to uninstall R Studio but simply download the version in the above link?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want newer, go here:  https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Do I uninstall my current R Studio and then install a newer version?

Comment: I use `.deb` packages and they upgrade very cleanly.   That should hold for most distros but as you didn't say what you use ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just update the RStudio from RStudio.
Help --> Check for updates

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall.
You can download and install the new version of R Studio with no issues. I've done so many times on my windows PC. 
Not sure of behaviour on linux & clones.
The new version you install should automatically point to your latest R version also and if not you can easily tell it to in the tools global options menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just update R Studio instead of uninstalling it. Even if you have downloaded you can give change and repair and install it rather uninstalling it.